# How can you/Is it feasible to override Doctrine_Connection in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

The university servers I'm currently working on lack PDO drivers, hence I've had to re-implement PDO & it's respective MySQL class to allow doctrine to connect to a MySQL database.

This is all well and good (or as well as a PHP implementation of PDO *can* go) and obviously if uni didn't have PDO at all this would all just work.

However, since they have PDO but no **drivers**, this means I can't re-instantiate PDO and have therefore called it _PDO. This change means that Doctrine_Connection has to be updated in order to implement the correct PDO (and run the correct static checkAvailableDrivers() method) whilst obviously I've changed the core class for testing this is less than ideal.

Does anyone know which classes to override in order to get to the instantiation of Doctrine_Connection? and or can provide examples?

I'm thinking it's something along the lines of going through:

sfDoctrineDatabase (in database.yml) -> Doctrine_Manager -> Doctrine_Connection

But I can't be sure?

Comment: Why don't you ask for pdo_mysql to be enabled?

Comment: Rewriting PDO in php is highly unrealistic, so I'd give it a try.

Comment: If you read the question further you'd see that I've already done it. The code is based on this: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2572-PHP-PDO-database-abstraction-interface-for-PHP-4.html, simply updated any deprecated syntax. The issue I have is moving the instantiation of the custom PDO out of Symfony core (so that it is per convention).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that writing a custom connection is what you're looking for: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/connections/en#writing-custom-connections

Comment: Cool, ta, that definitely looks relevant- but more specifically I'm looking for where to do this? What Symfony class would I need to override to insert the stuff inserted into boostrap.php in the example?

Comment: try putting it in a method called configureDoctrine in your projectConfiguration class.

Comment: configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager) in your ProjectConfiguration class is a perfect place for it.